# array in java methods, what is executed?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have been struggling with this java problem for several days now, and now I have to give up. I have been told the answer which should be 5 5 3 3, but I cannot in any way see how it is possible to get that result.

**Given the following java method:**

```
public int[] methodName(int[] nums)
{
     int largestOdd=0;
     for(int i=nums.length-2;i>=0;i--)
     {
          if (nums[i+1] % 2 != 0 && nums[i+1] > largestOdd)
               largestOdd = nums[i+1];

          if (nums[i] == 0)
               nums[i] = largestOdd;
     }
     return(nums);
}
```

What is printed when the following Java statements are executed?

```
int[] nums = {0,5,0,3};
nums = methodName(nums)
for (int i = 0; i<nums.length;i++)
    System.out.print(nums[i] + "");
System.out.println();
```

It just doesnt make any sense for me that first of all it will start printing "5". In my opinion it should be "3" because nums[2+1] = 3 (last index element)

Second of all why will it print four numbers when the loop in the method only will loop through 3 times until hitting -1 ?

If someone can explain how to get the result in a understandable way, I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're confusing length with available indices. available indices is 0 - 3, but the length is 4 (4 elements)

Comment: I know but the for loop will loop through 2,1 and 0, and when the answer is supposed print four elements thats where I start getting confused.

Comment: the method doesn't do any printing. It just returns a new reformatted array of the same size as the original array. So when you print the array from your bottom code, it still has for items.

Comment: The first loop only needs to use indices 2, 1, 0 to make the adjustments because index 3 is already 3. So when the loop makes the adjustments, it makes the second 0, 3, then the second iteration nothing, then the final iteration, makes the index 0, 5, giving you {5, 5, 3, 3}. See my answer for more details

Comment: Ahh ok I see, thanks peeskillet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`methodName` runs backwards through the array, examining every pair of numbers. In this case, the first pair examined will be (0,3).

As it runs over the pairs, `methodName` keeps track of the largest odd number seen (it looks at the *second* number of each pair for this).

Whenever the first number is zero, it sets it to the largest odd number seen so far.

So in this case, it will:

1. Look at (0,3).
2. Is 3 odd? Yes. Is it the largest odd number seen so far? Yes. So keep track of 3.
3. Is 0 zero? Yes. So set it to 3. Now the array is {0, 5, 3, 3}.
4. Move our indices back by 1 and look at (5, 3).
5. Is 3 odd? Yes. Is it the largest odd number seen so far? No.
6. Is 5 zero? No.
7. Move our indices back by 1 and look at (0, 5).
8. Is 5 odd? Yes. Is it the largest odd number seen so far? Yes. So keep track of 5.
9. Is 0 zero? Yes. So set it to 5. Now the array is {5, 5, 3, 3}.
10. We are already at the beginning of the array, so we can't go back any further.
11. Return to the main method, and print the contents of the array.

Comment: Wow thank you so much Alex, that was a really useful and understandable explanation. Makes so much more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
{0,5,0,3}

for(int i=nums.length-2;i>=0;i--) // starts at 0 (index 2) <-> num.length 4 - 2

   // runs 3 times  num.length(4) - 2 = 0

   if (nums[i+1] % 2 != 0 && nums[i+1] > largestOdd)
           largestOdd = nums[i+1]; <-->  // 3

           // if odd and grater than 0 
           // first iteration largestOdd = 3


   if (nums[i] == 0)   // still i is index 2 {0, 5, 0, 3} = 0, so true
          nums[i] = largestOdd;  // nums[i] (index 2) = 3

          // after first iteration
          {0, 5, 3, 3}


  Second iteration do nothing (0 is not odd)

  Third iteration, do same as first iteration, making final array
  {5, 5, 3, 3}
```

Next Part

```
 // This method returns the same array you passed into to
 public int[] methodName(int[] nums)
 {
     return(nums);
  }

 // So
 nums = methodName(nums) = {5, 5, 3, 3} The new array produced by the method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can analyse step by step.
In the for-loop: i starts from 2 to 0;
num = [0,5,0,3]
1.
    i = 2; largestOdd = 0;   nums[i+1] = nums[3] = 3;   nums[i] = nums[2] = 0;
    first condition "(nums[i+1] % 2 != 0 && nums[i+1] > largestOdd)" is true
        largestOdd = nums[i+1] = 3
    second condition (nums[i] == 0) is true
        nums[i] = nums[2] = largestOdd = 3
    nums = [0,5,3,3];
 2.
    i=1;   largestOdd = 3;   nums[i+1] = nums[2] = 3;   nums[i] = nums[1] = 5;
    first condition is false;
    second condition is false;
    nums = [0,5,3,3];
 3.
    i=0;  largestOdd = 3;   nums[i+1] = nums[1] = 5;   nums[i] = nums[0] = 0;
    first condition is true
         largestOdd = 5;
    second condition nums[0] = 0    is true
         nums[0] = largestOdd = 5;
    nums = [5,5,3,3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop 1 start i=2,nums=[0,5,0,3],largestOdd=0
because:(nums[2+1]=3)/2 !=0 && (nums[2+1]=3)>(largestOdd=0)
so:largestOdd=(nums[2+1]=3)=3
beacuse:(nums[2]=0) ==0
so:nums[2]=(largestOdd=3)=3
Loop 1 end   i=2,nums=[0,5,3,3],largestOdd=3

Loop 2 start i=1,nums=[0,5,3,3],largestOdd=3
because:(nums[1+1]=3)/2 !=0 && (nums[1+1]=3)>(largestOdd=3)
so:next
beacuse:(nums[1]=5) !=0
so:next
Loop 2 end   i=1,nums=[0,5,3,3],largestOdd=3

Loop 3 start i=0,nums=[0,5,3,3],largestOdd=3
because:(nums[0+1]=5)/2 !=0 && (nums[0+1]=5)>(largestOdd=3)
so:largestOdd=(nums[0+1]=5)=5
beacuse:(nums[0]=0) ==0
so:nums[0]=(largestOdd=5)=5
Loop 3 end   i=0,nums=[5,5,3,3],largestOdd=5

END LOOP
```